# vectorize a for loop containing hirarcial strings in python

Tags: python, vectorization

I have a code written using for loop, I wonder if there is a solution to vectorize it? My problem is that the order of the elements is important and is used in the if clause.
The code below describes that it need to count the number of apple and orange which exist between start and stop. another condition is that if the group (start-stop subarray) happens 2 times then multiply the number of apples by 2.

Codes:

```
import numpy as np

array = ["start","apple","orange","stop","chery","start","chery","orange","stop","apple","start","chery","apple","stop","apple"]
check=False
count_apple=0
count_orange=0
counter=0
for i in array:
    if i=="start" and check==False:
            check=True

    if check==True and i =="apple":
            count_apple+=1

    if check ==True and i == "orange":
            count_orange+=1

    if i=="stop" and check==True:
            check =False
            counter += 1
            if counter == 2:
                count_apple *= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not 100% vectorized but I am afraid that is not possible for the `count_orange` because the order of the data matters. Nevertheless it is definitely faster and more concise than your original code.

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

array = ["start","apple","orange","stop","chery","start","chery","orange","stop","apple","start","chery","apple","stop","apple"]

# Find start and stop entries
start_i = np.where(array == np.array('start'))[0]
stop_i =  np.where(array == np.array('stop'))[0]

# Create slices for indexes that should be used
slices = [slice(start+1, stop) for start, stop in zip(start_i, stop_i)]

# Apple counter multiplier
apple_multiplier = [2 if i == 2 else 1 for i in range(len(slices))]

# Not vectorized
count_apple = sum(array[s].count('apple') * m for s, m in zip(slices, apple_multiplier))
count_orange = sum(array[s].count('orange') for s in slices)

# Vectorized 
i = [list(range(start, stop)) for start, stop in zip(start_i, stop_i)]
i = list(chain.from_iterable(i))
count_orange = (np.array(array)[i] == 'orange').sum()
```

Comment: The code works fine. Only problem is that apple should be counted as 2 as there are 2 "apple" between start/stop. However, the code counted 3. I think it is because the last "apple" is counted after a start, But there is no stop to count it. That was the reason I used False/True. Is there a way to use False/Ture when vectorizing?

Comment: It is counting 3 apples because of the multiplier when counter is equal to 2. If you run your original code it also counts 3 apples. The last apple in the array is not being considered, otherwise it would count 4.